# How to call API in background so that it not affect in other process?

Tags: swift, sqlite, api, collectionview, reloaddata

I have `collectionview` with custom layout like pintrest, first I load 10 images, then when user reached at half of `scroll` request is fired , I've fetch data from sql local database, every time when app open API call , I have to call API in such way that affect other process:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {}
```

Using  **`alamofire`**  to call API,
if I fetch data in background from SQL database the app crashes, so I can't fetch data in background thread. However, it hangs scrolling. 
Also, when I reload data every for 10 new records `collectionview` jerks and it slows down the scroll speed. How to handle these both issues?

Comment: i don't understand why you cannot fetch data on another thread than main thread? If it crashes, find out why it crashes...i cannot believe that you cannot fetch data in another thread than main thread...

Comment: if i fetch it in another thread than app freeze. i mean from other thread to main queue scroll is freezing . currently i m using only DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {} this . and perfrom UI work in main queue.

Comment: then show us your code and let's find out why your app freezes....